# Na prática microserviços são executáveis separados?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software, microsserviços

Microsserviços é um assunto que sempre escuto em alta, porém sempre que vou para implementação as coisas ficam estranhas e começam a não condizer com a teoria de quebrar a aplicação em partes menores, sempre que vejo algum tutorial de implementação por exemplo, em Go vejo colocando todo os serviços no mesmo executável final.

Porém ao ouvir o episódio #349 do Hipsters Ponto Tech isso me pareceu mais estranho ainda, pois vi que num microsserviço ocorre de ter uma equipe trabalhando apenas em um serviço com commits e pr separadas, outra coisa que não fez sentido é: Se todos os serviços estão no mesmo executável então para quê serviços de mensageria como RabbitMq ou gRPC? A teoria parece linda, mas sempre que aparece um guia de microsserviços mais parece o que chamam de monólito.

Comment: Vi uma postagem que dizia o seguinte: *"Quantos bancos de dados principais  tem seu sistema? Se for somente 1, então você não implementa MS. Se tem mais de 1 bd, e se esse banco cair, quantas funcionalidades do seu sistema vão ficar offline? Se for ficar todas offline, então você não implementa MS"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsserviços é um assunto em alta, mas não é algo com uso em alta. Praticamente ninguém precisa disto e poucos usam de fato, mas são barulhentos. Ele tem um malefício importante de complexidade, chega-se dizer que é o problema mais difícil de resolver na computação, e tem ganhos que podem ser obtidos de outra forma. Então as pessoas precisam entender o que é marketing e o que é engenharia.

É tão complicado que muita gente diz estar fazendo sem estar. A pessoa sequer aprende direito o que é, faz alguma coisa, mas para estar na moda diz que fez. Mais ou menos como acontece com outras coisas, por exemplo com orientação a objeto que a maioria faz errado, em alguns casos até para o bem. Fazer algo que não é microsserviços é bem mais fácil, então pode não ser tão ruim a pessoa só chamar assim, ainda que nunca será bom ela dar nome para algo que nem é de fato aquilo, mostra falta de entendimento muito grande da profissão.

E sim, na internet está cheio de informação falsa, especialmente na nossa área. Parte por ingenuidade das pessoas que replicam coisas falsas, porque gostam de estar na moda, parte por alguma forma de má fé, muitas vezes porque alguém ganha dinheiro vendendo a ideia. Em alguns raros casos as pessoas não perceberam que aquilo seria mal usado.

Você pode quebrar sua aplicação em muitos executáveis e não estar usando microsserviços, mas não pode colocar tudo em um executável e ser microsserviços.

A definição dele implica em execuções separadas, em instâncias isoladas, e que permita fazer o *deploy* independente das outras partes.

Na verdade, nem é sobre executáveis, é sobre isolamento total. Ou seja, se você tem executáveis separados, mas tem ligações com outras partes, banco de dados por exemplo, já não é arquitetura de microsserviços. E é muito comum ver separar em executáveis, mas usar o mesmo banco de dados. Isso está errado pela definição, mas talvez certo pela solução real, só não pode chamar de microsserviços.

Parte do benefício é a escala, e colocar tudo no mesmo executável impede isso. Parte é permitir que as equipes trabalhem de forma independente não precisando ter que juntar tudo em uma coisa com as partes das outras equipes. Então se juntar no mesmo executável não faz o menor sentido.

Se for para todo mundo trabalhar na mesma coisa então está usando arquitetura monolítica, o que pode ser bem melhor.

Qualquer pessoa séria na área, que entenda de microsserviços, falará mais para você não o usar do que para usar. Depois ela pode explicar como fazer se quiser insistir. Mas por ser algo tão pouco necessário, seria melhor nem falar muito.

Este site costuma estar entre os 50 mais acessados, A Wikipedia entre os 5, parecido com o Instagram, e tem vários outros assim, todos que não usam microsserviços. Se a pessoa não puder justificar fortemente não deve nem cogitar o uso. Todas as vezes que eu palestrei sobre, ouvi "no nosso caso precisava mesmo", mas nunca alguém conseguiu justificar que precisava de verdade, as pessoas dão "justificativas" genéricas, no fundo só quer estar na moda.

Pra ser sincero não vi ninguém fazendo tudo em um executável só, mas eu não duvido existir não, já vi coisas piores se espalhando na internet.

Se for algo simples seria uma loucura usar microsserviços, se for complexo a pessoa não tem a noção da dificuldade de fazer isso. Você sequer consegue testar algo assim em seu próprio computador, por melhor que ele seja. Precisa ter uma infra sofisticada para lidar com isso. Eu já vi empresas praticamente criarem um sistema operacional em uma equipe dedicada para gerenciar tudo isso. Parece que já tem gente comercializando soluções assim de tão complicado que é.

Nem vou dizer como a eficiência sofre, como os custos vão lá pra cima.

Microsserviços é complexidade que pode ajudar gerenciar complexidade extrema por isolar completamente a aplicação em pequenas partes completamente independentes. Se tiver até mesmo uma dependência abstrata já pode complicar. Uma dependência assim obriga um microsserviço não fazer certas alterações para não prejudicar o outro microsserviço, e isso já matou a arquitetura.

Existem formas de obter o mesmo benefício sem usar microsserviços, mas em quase todas, mesmo sendo considerada uma arquitetura monolítica, precisa de vários executáveis. Imagine em microsserviços.

A técnica foi interessante para as pessoas aprenderem certas formas de fazer, de pegar conhecimento adquirido para usar alguns pontos, mas não para adotar a arquitetura. A independência de *deploy* por exemplo pode ser útil para todo mundo que tem uma equipe grande, mas isso pode ser feito em solução monolítica. Mesmo isso não pode ser feito em um executável monolítico, que não cosias diferentes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Tem essa questão do banco também que esqueci de mencionar acima

Comment: Colocar tudo no mesmo banco de dados é fácil de fazer, mas aí não tem os benefícios do ms, e portanto, não é microsserviço. Separar obriga você realizar na aplicação tudo o que o banco de dados já az por você, boa sorte em ser tão bom quanto e ter mais recursos que os implementadores de bancos de dados :P :)

Comment: note que ter algum microsserviço isolado pode ser útil. Por exemplo a autenticação ou algo específico de alguma área que já seja naturalmente isolada, e tem apenas um ponto de comunicação com o resto, mas isso não pode ser chamado de arquitetura de microsserviços.